# Upgrading from Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: upgrade

I haven't upgraded Ubuntu in a while and am stuck with Ubuntu 10.10. When I click on upgrade all it says..your version is no longer supported. How do I upgrade then?

Comment: See also [How to install software or upgrade from old unsupported release?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release)